# How to implement onAcitvityResult in React Native Android?

Tags: android, react-native

How to implement the *onActivityResult* in React Native module
I want to to check the result of launched activity in React Native.
Here it shows  the error as '''cannot find symbole onActivityResult```

```java
public class RNWhatsAppStickersModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {
...
 public RNWhatsAppStickersModule(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        super(reactContext);
        this.reactContext = reactContext;
    }

 @Override
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        try {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE  && resultCode  == RESULT_OK) {

                String requiredValue = data.getStringExtra("key");
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Toast.makeText(Activity.this, ex.toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

  }
...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
    public final ActivityEventListener mActivityEventListener = new BaseActivityEventListener(){

        @Override
        public void onActivityResult(Activity activity, int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
            Log.d("ReactNative",String.valueOf(requestCode));
            Log.d("ReactNative",String.valueOf(resultCode));
     
            // check out the codes on accepting and rejecting the activity
        }
        
    };
```

In your constructor, Add something like this

```java
      reactContext.addActivityEventListener(mActivityEventListener);
```

http://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-android#getting-activity-result-from-startactivityforresult

Comment: this conflict with other module with onActivityResult